# this.xxxx.emit is not a function

Tags: angular7, mouseclick-event, angular-event-emitter

```
    I'm having issues with errors regarding `@Output` and `@EventEmitter` in Angular7.


        <button (click)="updateStatus()" class="btn btn-primary" >Valider</button>

    Code handling the click-event in the component:  
    import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges  } from '@angular/core';

 @Input()
      set selectedCommande(value: Command) {
        this._selectedCommande = value;
      }
      get selectedCommande(): Command {
        return this._selectedCommande;
      }
```

//this catch the value in the first time , but after it fails
          @Output() putSelectedCommand =  new EventEmitter();

```
        updateStatus() {
             this.putSelectedCommand.emit(this._selectedCommande);
        }

    Error: 
    >TypeError: this.putSelectedCommand.emit is not a function
```

Comment: Please show your import statements.

Comment: Please share a  minimal reproducible example of the component that you have. At least all imports in components

Comment: first time, the eventEmitter is working but afterthat, it fails.import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges  } from '@angular/core';
import {Client} from '../../../rex-ihm-common/models/client.model';
import {Contract} from '../../../rex-ihm-common/models/contract.model';
import {Command} from '../../../rex-ihm-common/models/command.model';
import { Advisor } from 'src/app/rex-ihm-common/models/advisor.model';